What kind of communication is physical demonstration?
Imagine a species of a proto-humans that have yet to develop any form of spoken language. There is a proto-human, Greg, who roams around with another proto-human, Larry.
Greg, from past experience, knows the location of a beehive full of honey, and Greg desires that Larry also know the location. In the absence of spoken language, Greg devises a means by which to convey this information. He picks up Larry and forcefully carries him to the beehive, where Larry then sees it for himself.
What is the nature of this form of communication? I wouldn't call it 'language', because there are no symbols being used. But, is Greg forming propositions in his head? Those propositions being "There is honey at this location. I want Larry to know this."
I'm trying to pinpoint what exactly separates language from other forms of communication, but I'm having trouble defining what communication is. Does there have to be an intent to communicate for there to be communication?

Hello and welcome to the site! Unfortunately broader communication and semiotics isn't really on-topic here. I'm inclined to close this, but lets see what the rest of the community thinks.
